# In javascript how to trim and get only 100 from '/projects/100' string?

Tags: javascript

I need to trim my string and want to get only the last charecter after '/' , how to do split and trim to get last  char ,

eg : `'/projects/100'`

i want 100 in return after trim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
'/projects/100'.split('/')[2]
```

Comment: Please at least demonstrate how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = '/projects/100';
var splits = string.split('/');

console.log(splits[splits.length - 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression

```js
const str = '/projects/100'
const [res] = str.match(/[0-9]+$/g)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String example = "/projects/100";
System.out.println(example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
```